# GZipStream Decompress not unzipping complete file

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream

I am trying to unzip .gz files using GZipStream. It will only exctract 12kb of the file but if I use winzip or 7zip to unzip the .gz file the extracted file should be 753kb. See the code below that I am using, any pointers on where I am going wrong?

```
public bool StartLibZipExtraction()
    {
        bool returnResult = false;

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(m_ProjectPath);

            foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
            {
                // check if this is the file to UNZIP
                if (fileToDecompress.Name.Equals(m_ZipFileName))
                {
                    returnResult = true;        // unzip successful
                    Agent.LogInfo("~~~ Unzipping file: " + fileToDecompress.ToString() + " ~~~");
                    Decompress(fileToDecompress);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Agent.LogInfo("*** StartLibZipExtraction() Error: " + e.Message + " ***");
            return false;
        }
        return returnResult;
    }


    public void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
        {
            string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
            string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);


            using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                    Agent.LogInfo(decompressionStream.ToString());
                    Agent.LogInfo("Decompressed: {0}" + fileToDecompress.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks alright. The error is somewhere else e.g. in code not shown or you confused the files or you misread the file size or there was an error mid-way that you did not see or ...

Comment: In particular, `returnResult` ends up true in case of error. I advise you to rethink your error handling. This kind of early catch and return bool is an anti pattern. Let exceptions bubble up to where they can be handled.